# How do you create a semi-transaparent image in numpy and saving it in pillows as PNG

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Hello I would like to create a semi-transparent image. What i thought would be straight forward turns out not to be. I created a 1000x1000 pixel array with a depth of 4 (B,G,R,A channels). I initialized them to all 0 thinking that they would produce full black but also fully transparent base image. I then draw a green shape at 50% transaparency, in this case a square to make the code very minimal,

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2

blankImage = np.zeros((1000,1000,4))
BGRAcolor = (38,255,0,125) # 50% transaparent light green

blankImage[250:250, 750:750] = BGRAcolor

#Image.fromarray(blankImage).save('result.png') #throws an error

cv2.imshow("blankImage", blankImage)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Problem is i cannot save the image as a .png because PIL throws an error, hence i cannot confirm if i have correctly made the image or not. Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.....\Image.py", line 3098, in fromarray
    mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: ((1, 1, 4), '<f8')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\.....\transparentImage.py", line 25, in <module>
    Image.fromarray(testImage).save('result.png')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\.....\Image.py", line 3102, in fromarray
    raise TypeError(msg) from e
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 4), <f8
```

Alternativly i tried using opencv imshow() to preview the images, but I really cant tell if open cv shows transparent pixels as black or if i have messed up making/assigning values to my alpha layer. Also the color is white for some reason and not green.

Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Pardon that the square became a rectangle strip.

[image]

Comment: Clean up your example code, there's no `testImage` created.

Comment: `np.zeros((1000,1000,4))` -- you should explicitly specify `dtype=np.uint8`. As is, it's an array of 64bit floats, which is rather unusual for an image in the first place, and PIL doesn't seem to like it (even if it did work, it would probably expect intensities in range 0.0-1.0).

Comment: Also, you're already using OpenCV there, so why not just `cv2.imwrite`?

Comment: @MarkRansom my bad, i corrected them now.

Comment: @DanMašek good point... i actually dont know why i hadnt thought of that... im probably out of mental energy right now. and yes `cv2.imwrite` works no problem. the image is now colored green,  and have a transaparent background.. Im going to use this method, but i guess the answer that i have to accept should still use PIL when saving though as that is what i had originally placed in the tittle. Oh by the way adding `dtype=np.uint8` solve that problem too, pillows now accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.

First, you need to create a numpy array of dtype np.uint8.

```py
blankImage = np.zeros((1000, 1000, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Second, you are using slice incorrectly.

```py
blankImage[top:bottom, left:right] = BGRAcolor
```

Here is the corrected code.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

testImage = np.zeros((1000, 1000, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
BGRAcolor = (38, 255, 0, 125)  # 50% transaparent light green

testImage[250:750, 250:750] = BGRAcolor

Image.fromarray(testImage).save('result.png')
```

Comment: Apologize for the slicing, im actually aware of the proper format, i was just playing with the shape. My sample code is all over the place :D. Anyway the `dtype=np.uint8` solved all the issue. Thanks so much !